# What does it mean for Latent Dirichlet Allocation results to be "good"?

Tags: clustering, text-mining

In most paper, Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) model is used for clustering, and the value of $K$ is trained manually (e.g. http://astro.temple.edu/~tua95067/grbovic_cikm.pdf). They claim that this value has a good balance between total and individual coverage.

- I don't know how to define the "total coverage" and "individual coverage".
- Is there a good method to train the value of K, not manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`K` is the number of topics for your model. Just like in any other clustering problem, choosing the right number of clusters is very problem/data-specific and usually is chosen manually/randomly.

To estimate the number of clusters `K`, non-parametric methods can be used, for example, the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process (HDP) described by [Wang et al.](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chongw/papers/WangPaisleyBlei2011.pdf)

In the paper you link to, however, (at a glance) it seems like they are trying to find a number of topics `K` that evenly distributes their instances ("e-mails") across all *folders*. Note that this last point about folders is not LDA-specific!

- their *coverage* for a topic `k` is the number of emails for that topic associated to that folder;
- next they require that a topic should cover at least 50% of all emails in that folder to be *dominant* (in that folder)

Say you have 10 emails in 2 folders X and Y and do an LDA with a `K` of three (topics A-C) and you get:

- 6 mails in folder X: 3 A, 2 B, 1 C
- 4 mails folder Y: 1 A, 1 C, 2 C

NB: I could not confirm that each email is only assigned to one folder, but I assume this is the case.

Now they define **total coverage** as the *traffic* (i.e., the total proportion of emails) where their topic covers 50% of all mails in a folder. In our case we get:

For topic A, the *individual coverage* is **30%**:

- in folder X, it is dominant/has 50%, and represents **30%** of all mail
- in folder Y, it has less than 50%, so we ignore it

For topic B, the individual coverage is 0%:

- is not dominant in any folder

For topic C, the *individual coverage* is 20%:

- 50% in folder Y, accounting for **20%** of all mail

Thus, for this outcome, *total coverage* would be 30% plus 20% = 50%.

Their strategy now is to find an "optimal" `K` that maximizes this total coverage while also ensuring high individual (per-topic) coverages.
This means, their method of defining `K` uses "external information" not part of the LDA process itself, namely the folder-assignments of emails by users (which are independent of the topic assignments by the LDA).